# Android XML Layout Auto Scale

Tags: android, xml, layout, scale

On different screen sizes, my layout becomes smaller than expected.
So is there any way to make the layout keep the same ratio on all screens?
In other words, how can I scale my layout?

Mylayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!--  One Two Button -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    >


     <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/one_btn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/border"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:padding="20dp" >

           <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/one_picture"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     </RelativeLayout>


     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/two_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="20dp" >

           <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/two_picture"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<!--  Three Four Button -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    >


        <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/three_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/border"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:padding="20dp" >

              <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/three_picture"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/four_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/border"
           android:padding="20dp" >

              <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/four_picture"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!--  Five Six Button -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    >


     <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/five_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="20dp" >

                <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/five_picture"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
      </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/six_btn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/border"
          android:padding="20dp" >

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/six_picture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ex30"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ex30.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/xoFaJ.jpg]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/jISJD.jpg]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/P7LHs.jpg]

Comment: Look into using LinearLayout's weight property.

Comment: I think that my layout using drawable-mdpi Instead of drawable xhdpi.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/naP5c.jpg :(

Comment: Check out these two links, they may be helpful:

http://www.quadra-tec.net/~floppie/blag/2013/01/scalinglinearlayout-auto-scaling-layouts-in-android/

http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Scaling_Android_Apps_White_Paper.pdf